# TypeError when trying to get a list of names in Pyton

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm pretty new to python and I'm trying to get a list of names from an website using the following code:

This is the original code, which returns a lot of data, from which I am trying to extract the 'firstname' only

```
import requests

url = "https://x.gorgias.com/api/users?limit=30&order_by=name%3Aasc&roles=agent"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Basic x"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I removed the auth key and the link since this is a code for our company. Here is the response that I get from this code:

```
{"data": [{"id": 602001443, "external_id": null, "active": true, "email": "email@company.com", "bio": null, "name": "Agent Name1 ", "firstname": "Agent Name1", "lastname": "", "roles": [{"id": 58506, "name": "agent"}], "role": {"id": 58506, "name": "agent"}, "created_datetime": "2022-06-01T18:14:19.081362+00:00", "updated_datetime": "2022-06-01T18:19:56.196404+00:00", "deactivated_datetime": null, "meta": {"name_set_via": "agent"}, "data": null, "has_password": true, "has_2fa_enabled": false}, {"id": 602001740, "external_id": "112351259267296708113", "active": true, "email": "email@company.com"...
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the 'firstname' attribute and this is what I've did:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://x.gorgias.com/api/users?limit=30&order_by=name%3Aasc&roles=agent"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": "Basic"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
text = json.loads(response.text)
final_text = text['data']['firstname']

print(final_text)
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
final_text = text['data']['firstname']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I fix this error in order for me to extract only the firstname from that list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is a list, so you need to iterate over it

```
for item in text[“data”]:
    final_text=item[”firstname”]
```

Or `text[“data”][0][“firstname”]` if you need only one item in data